# How to copy folder from one server to another with different domain using c#

Tags: c#, .net

I need to copy many folders from a server to another server. The servers are in different domains. Is tcp or ftp should be used? I am having the login credentials to access the server.
Is it possible to use something like

```
string sourceFile = @"ServerIP\C:\Users\Public\public\test.txt";
string destinationFile = @"Localhost\C:\Users\Public\private\test.txt";

// To move a file or folder to a new location:
System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destinationFile);
```

Comment: I tried a couple of methods.Atlast now succeeded. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can grab the idea of doing it using the code snippet below. You can use [LogonUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378184.aspx) to impersonate a local group also not only domain accounts.

To copy all the contents (files) inside the Directory/Folder, obviously you can use the `Directory` class from inside `System.IO` namespace to get all the files information.

Code:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Security.Permissions;

public class Form1
{
    [DllImport("advapi32.DLL", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int LogonUser(string lpszUsername, string lpszDomain, string lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, ref IntPtr phToken);
    private void Button1_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        IntPtr admin_token = default(IntPtr);
        WindowsIdentity wid_current = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        WindowsIdentity wid_admin = null;
        WindowsImpersonationContext wic = null;
        try {
            MessageBox.Show("Copying file...");
            if (LogonUser("Local Admin name", "Local computer name", "pwd", 9, 0, ref admin_token) != 0) {
                wid_admin = new WindowsIdentity(admin_token);
                wic = wid_admin.Impersonate();
                System.IO.File.Copy("C:\\right.bmp", "\\\\157.60.113.28\\testnew\\right.bmp", true);
                MessageBox.Show("Copy succeeded");
            } else {
                MessageBox.Show("Copy Failed");
            }
        } catch (System.Exception se) {
            int ret = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            MessageBox.Show(ret.ToString(), "Error code: " + ret.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
        } finally {
            if (wic != null) {
                wic.Undo();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Reference: [Impersonate with Local Account](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vblanguage/thread/b9906632-5cad-4972-9103-3e864a71a0c2/)

Comment: I will try this and let you know. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

> Is it possible to use something like ?

Shouldn't you find out that yourself ?

For

> I need to copy many folders from a server to another server

To work with FTP, you will need to use `System.Net.FtpWebRequest` and `System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp`,

see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequestmethods.ftp.aspx.

Also a simple search on google gave many good ways of doing this, https://www.google.co.in/search?q=copy+files+from+one+server+to+another+using+asp.net

Please try one of these, and when you have problems when implementing them, should you come here and ask 'that' question. Not the other way round.