# How to copy file from one server to other which is in different enviroment

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file, automation

I want to copy file from one server to other server using **any automation process**.

Both servers are in **different environment**, I've got access of both environment.

e.g.
**server1 is in env1 , server2 in in env2**

and I want to copy file from server1 C:\test\copy.txt **to** server2 C:\test\

**Note: Using Windows server.**

I've added code below using this i can copy file if both servers are in same VPN , but in my scenario both servers are in different VPN.

```
    public void copyFile()
    {
        IntPtr admin_token = default(IntPtr);
        WindowsIdentity wid_current = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        WindowsIdentity wid_admin = null;
        WindowsImpersonationContext wic = null;
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Copying file...");
            if (LogonUser("LocalUsername", "LocalDomain", "LocalPass", 9, 0, ref admin_token) != 0)
            {
                wid_admin = new WindowsIdentity(admin_token);
                wic = wid_admin.Impersonate();
                System.IO.File.Copy("C:\\test\\copy.txt", "\\\\Server2\\test\\copy.txt", true);
                Console.WriteLine("Copy succeeded");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Copy Failed");
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception se)
        {
            int ret = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            Console.WriteLine(ret.ToString(), "Error code: " + ret.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(se.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (wic != null)
            {
                wic.Undo();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does it requiere user and password on the other machine?

Comment: @NicoRiff i found on reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132926/how-to-copy-folder-from-one-server-to-another-with-different-domain-using-c-shar/13133018#13133018

Comment: but it doesn't help. i'm getting username or password incorrect error.

Comment: I just removed the [tag:c#] tag, because I cannot see anything C#-related in your question; if you want a C# solution you can readd the tag -- but then also provide the code you already have!

Comment: @aschipfl actually i had mentioned link earlier in comment , but now I've also added code for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Map out one of the server as a network drive and use XCOPY ?
check out:

https://superuser.com/questions/206036/commmand-line-command-to-copy-entire-directory-including-directory-folder-to-a/206037

Answer (score 0):

If you have permissions on both servers and both support FTP servers - IIS on windows server allows this - this could be one possible solution.

With FTP enabled you could write a simple program that could sit on either machines, or another machine. This would allow you to move files between the two servers. Many programming languages support FTP operations, C# through the `FtpWebRequest` class, documentation for which can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script, something like this:

```
net use \\Server2 /user:yourUser yourPassword
ROBOCOPY C:\test\copy.txt \\Server2\test\
```

The only thing you need, is to share the test folder with the user `yourUser` and execute the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code(you would have to implement Impersonator class https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10090/A-small-C-Class-for-impersonating-a-User):

```
using ( new Impersonator( "remoteUsername", "remoteDomain", "remotePassword" ) )
{
   File.Copy("C:\test\copy.txt", "\\anotherMachine\c$\test\copy.txt" );
}
```

The code above assumes you got the user that have the required permission.

Comment: can i use this if both servers are in different VPN?

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "different VPN", but basically if you can see your destination from your origin, then yes it is going to work. Logically it wont work if you can´t see the destination computer